# Can't run tmate as daemon programatically

Tags: node.js

I have an app which runs as sudo and it is started using pm2. It must run as sudo.

Inside it I run this function on startup:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
function getTmate(app) {
  exec('rm /tmp/tmate.sock display -p \'#{tmate_ssh}\'').catch(err => console.log(err));
  exec('tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p \'#{tmate_ssh}\'').catch(err => console.log(err)); //exception here
  setTimeout(async function () {
    let {stdout} = await exec('tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p \'#{tmate_ssh}\'').catch(err => console.log(err));
    if (stdout.length > 8) {
      console.log(stdout);
    }
    else {
      getTmate();
    }
  }, 15000);
}
```

but I never get to start tmate properly. On the second `exec` I receive the following error:

> failed to connect to server
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
> at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:401:11)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
> at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12)   killed: false,   code: 1,   signal: null,   cmd:    "tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock > display -p '#{tmate_ssh}'",   stdout: '',   stderr: 'failed to connect  to server\n' }
> ```

The idea is to run tmate at startup and send the ssh to my cloud server as soon as it is available. Any other approach is welcome. Also tried running `tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock new-session -d` on `/etc/rc.local` but I couldn't retrieve the ssh string later (same error)

If I run these commands in a terminal tmate works allright:

`tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock new-session -d`

`tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p '#{tmate_ssh}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took another approach that worked:

changed /etc/rc.local to the following:

```
su nvidia -c 'tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock new-session -d'
su nvidia -c 'tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock wait tmate-ready'
su nvidia -c "tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p '#{tmate_ssh}'  > /tmp/tmateSSH"
exit 0
```

and later I just retrieved /tmp/tmateSSH when it was available.